# Kafka Connect not working with Subject Strategies

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

**Context**

I coded a couple of small [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html) connectors. One that just generates random data each second and another that logs it in the console. They're integrated with a [Schema Registry](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/index.html) so the data is serialized with [Avro](https://avro.apache.org/).

I deployed them into a local Kafka environment using the [fast-data-dev Docker image provided by Landoop](https://github.com/Landoop/fast-data-dev)

The basic setup works and produces a message each second that is logged

However, I want to change the [subject name strategy](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html#subject-name-strategy). The default one generates two subjects:

- `${topic}-key`
- `${topic}-value`

As per my use case, I'll need to generate events with different schemas that will end up on the same topic. Therefore, the subject names I need are:

- `${topic}-${keyRecordName}`
- `${topic}-${valueRecordName}`

As per [the docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html#subject-name-strategy), my needs fits into the [TopicRecordNameStrategy](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/subject/TopicRecordNameStrategy.java)

**What have I tried**

I create the `avroData` object for sending values to connect:

```
class SampleSourceConnectorTask : SourceTask() {

    private lateinit var avroData: AvroData 

    override fun start(props: Map<String, String>) {
        [...]
        avroData = AvroData(AvroDataConfig(props))
    }
```

and use it afterwards for creating the `SourceRecord` response objects

[The documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/connect.html) states that in order to use the Schema Registry in Kafka Connect I have to set some properties in the connector config. Therefore, when I create it I add them:

```
name=SampleSourceConnector
connector.class=[...]
tasks.max=1
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
key.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy
value.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy
```

**Problem**

The connector seems to ignore those properties and keeps using the old `${topic}-key` and `${topic}-value` subjects.

**Question**

Kafka Connect is supposed to support different subject strategies. I managed to workaround the issue by writing my own version of the [`AvroConverter`](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-converter/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/avro/AvroConverter.java#L118) and hardcoding that the subject strategy is the one I need. However, this doesn't look like a good approach and also brought issues when trying to consume the data with the Sink Kafka Connector. I duplicated the subject so there's a version with the old name (`${topic}-key`) and it works

What is the proper setup for specyfing the subject strategy to Kafka Connect?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're missing the `key.converter` and `value.converter` prefix, for the config to be passed through to the conveter. So instead of:

```
key.subject.name.strategy
value.subject.name.strategy
```

you want:

```
key.converter.key.subject.name.strategy
value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy
```

Source https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/configuring.html:

> To pass configuration parameters to key and value converters, prefix them with `key.converter.` or `value.converter.` as you would in the worker configuration when defining default converters. Note that these are only used when the corresponding converter configuration is specified in the `key.converter` or `value.converter` properties.

Comment: You're right. I didn't find anything related to that in the documentation (may I didn't dig enough). Do you have some link to some documentation stating that? That would complete the answer

Comment: Edited question to include reference

Comment: For context, this didn't work until Confluent 4.1.3, AFAIK. https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/pull/801