# How to map multiple topics which use different subject name strategies in kafka-connect-elasticsearch

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

Let's say I have two topics i.e Topic1 & Topic2. Topic1 uses TopicNameStrategy and Topic2 uses TopicRecordNameStrategy. How to configure these two topics?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is configured in the converter, and converters are configured either at the worker or connector level, you will need to create two connectors, each with the subject name strategy set according to the topic read by that connector.

See also [Kafka Connect not working with Subject Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53521661/kafka-connect-not-working-with-subject-strategies)