# Strange behaviour when using AvroConverter in Confluent Sink Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I was running confluent(v5.5.1) s3 sink connector with below config:

```
"value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
"value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://registryurl",
"value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy":"io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy",
......
```

And got below error in the log like:

```
DEBUG Sending GET with input null to http://registryurl/schemas/ids/309?fetchMaxId=false
DEBUG Sending POST with input {......} to http://registryurl/MyRecordName?deleted=true
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro value schema version for id 309
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Subject not found.; error code: 40401
```

There are 2 questions that baffles me here:

1. Why the sink connector sends additional **POST** request to schema registry given it's just a consumer? And I have successfully received messages when using a standard kafka consumer, which ONLY sends a **GET** request to the schema registry.
2. As per [this docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=148647365) and [official doc](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#how-the-naming-strategies-work), the schema subject format will be like **SubjectNamingStrategy-value or -key**. However judging by the log, it does not suffix the request with "-value". I have tried all the 3 strategies and found ONLY the default **TopicNameStrategy** works as expected.

Appreciated if anyone could shed some light here.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure that the producer isn't the one sending the POST? And the docs you linked to are for Flink, not written by Confluent

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer. Yes I'm sure, because the log is from my s3 sink connector only. If you are looking for an official Confluent doc, this [link](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#how-the-naming-strategies-work) should be the one, which also states so.

Comment: If the subject in the registry already exists, the POST is effectively a no-op. Code is open source if you really want to dig into why it happens. Also, maybe it's a version issue, but other people have had issues with the strategies in the past https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53521661/kafka-connect-not-working-with-subject-strategies